# Timer and TimerTask Java

Tags: java, timer, timertask

I want my program to print Hello User, a ten seconds later print Ten Seconds Have Gone By, finally, a few seconds later print Goodbye User. I just don't know what or how to start to do this. Thanks

Here's the code:

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
public class S1p4 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        Task task = new Task();
        timer.schedule(task, 1000, 1000);

}
```

}

```
class Task extends TimerTask {

    int i=1;
    @Override
    public void run() {
        i++;

        System.out.println("Hello User");


        if(i<=10){
            System.out.println("Ten Seconds Have Gone By");
    }

        System.out.println("Goodbye User");
            cancel();

            System.exit(0);

  }
```

}

EDIT 1: It would run good if I take out System.exit();, but what would I replace it with? Because I don't want a program that I have to stop.

Comment: Is "Hello user" should be printed on each second or only at the first time ?

Comment: @SeeTheC Only the first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
class Task extends TimerTask {

    int i=0;
    @Override
    public void run() {
        i++;
        if(i==1)
            System.out.println("Hello User");
        if(i==10){
            System.out.println("Ten Seconds Have Gone By");
        }
        if(i==13){
            System.out.println("Goodbye User");
            cancel();        
        }

    }
}
```

o/p :

First time it prints : Hello User
After 10 sec it prints : Ten sec has passed.
After 13 sec : Goodby User

Comment: Could this be used for countdonws?

Comment: ya , you can use it .

Answer (score 1):

The timer you're using is ok, we just need to apply Thread.sleep to resolve your problem.

```
class Task extends TimerTask {


    @Override
    public void run() {

        System.out.println("Hello User");

        try {

            Thread.sleep(10000);

            System.out.println("Ten Seconds Have Gone By");

            Thread.sleep(5000);

            System.out.println("Goodbye User");

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: I prefer not using Thread.sleep because I will be putting this into another part of my project that uses loops. Which can cause malfunction problems. What are other ways you suggest. Also, thank you for answering.